# How can I exclude any hosts in prometheus alerting rules

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

Here is my alert_rules.yml file

```
groups:
- name: http_alerts
  rules:
  - alert: ssl expire in 30 days
    expr: probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry - time() < 86400 * 30
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: "SSL certificate will expire soon on (instance {{ $labels.instance }})"
      description: "SSL certificate expires in 30 days\n  VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS: {{ $labels }}"
```

and here is my prometheus.yml file

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

rule_files:
  - 'alert.rules'

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - scheme: http
    static_configs:
    - targets: 
      - 'alertmanager:9093'

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'blackbox_http'
    scrape_timeout: 30s
    scrape_interval: 30s
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - https://google.com
        - https://github.com

    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: blackbox:9115
```

I want to exclude target *google.com* from alert_rules.yml for the certificate expiry checks. I want to keep *google.com* target in prometheus.yml as this target needs to be monitored for other use cases.

Comment: You can do so by simply filtering out google in your alert rule expressions. So instead of `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry` use `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{target!="https://google.com"}`

Comment: Thank you @markalex but can I exclude multiple targets. I didn't find any good documentation for this. If you have any reference please share that as well.

Comment: Then you can use `probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{target!="https://google.com", target!="https://target2.com"}`. Or regex selector `!~`, like `{target!~"https://(google|target2)\.com"}`. This is basic promQL, there are a lot of references on the Internet. And you can check your attempts of queries at web console at any moment.

Comment: @markalex this didn't worked. I added 'probe_ssl_earliest_cert_expiry{target!="https://google.com"} - time() < 86400 * 60' and still in prometheus it is showing certificate expiry of google.com